# Oracle client compatibility .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm using VS 2013 to build a app that connects to a oracle 10g. Because of some internal requirements this app has to be .Net 3.5 x64. But no matter what i cant get any of the Nuget Packages to work! Either they cant handle 3.5 or i get a strange generic Client Compatibility issue...
So I was wondering... if I go to oracle and download the latest client and install it on the machine that will run my app, will it work with .net 3.5 and 10g? because the site is quite vague about this kind of info and I don't like to just install stuff on a server... (don't get me wrong here! I can compile my app!)

Comment: Instead of trusting random people on the internet, why don't you test it in a testing environment?

Comment: money... I don't have a testing env because my boss/client cant afford it and rather have a eventual crash... that doesn't mean ill just go bananas on the server... sad I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the client does work, but you have to be very careful regarding the version (32 or 64) of the client. There is no "universal" package, and a 64 bit environment wont fallback to a 32 version of the client...